# list of dictionaries to csv. Each list in a row

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, export-to-csv

I'm new to dataframe here.

i have a list of dictionaries that i got from a python script:

```
result = [{'Name':'J','age':'5','address':'California'},
 {'Name':'Q', 'age':'10','address':'newYork'}
]
```

I want this output to be in a csv file where the column name is "info" and each dictionary is in a row.

Any idea how to get a csv like this :

```
    info
    {'Name':'J','age':'5','address':'California'}
    {'Name':'Q', 'age':'10','address':'newYork'}
```

Comment: The 'normal' way to represent it as CSV would be to have 3 columns 'name', 'age' and 'address'. Are you sure that you want to do what you ask for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an edited example from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) assuming that all dictionaries have the exact same keys:

```
import csv

with open('names.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=result[0].keys())

    writer.writeheader()
    for r in result:
        writer.writerow(r)
```

Comment: I got this error:AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: sorry, meant result[0].keys()

Answer (score 0):

Here, you are just writing JSON strings to a text file. Just do it:

```
import json

with out = open(filename, 'w', newline='\r\n'):    # CSV end of line
    print('info', file=out)
    for js in resul:
        print(json.dumps(js), file=out)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `pandas`, you can run the following:

```
 import pandas as pd
 pd.DataFrame({"info": result}).to_csv("something.csv", index=False)
```